# Skip token errors on Grpah API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Hello I am getting several skip token errors when running a full import on the graph API.

here is the error

1. The following one looks like expiration of skiptoken. Graph connector uses skip token in different cases. I would communicate with Graph API team to understand if this is correct behavior for the API.
   Message: Error during http call. HttpStatusCode: BadRequest; 
   url: https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/groups/5802115b-ef14-4572-bec1-9a4747e5bcfb/members/?$select=id&$skiptoken=X%2744537074090001000000000000000010000000D6203A9D758C6F4B887B307BA3302EB5000000000000000000000017312E322E3834302E3131333535362E312E342E323333310000000000000157F232736047814E848C20B3547FF5E8%27; 
   Response: {
   "error": {
   "code": "Directory_ExpiredPageToken",
   "message": "The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request.",
   "innerError": {
     "request-id": "1489b123-f94c-4531-82d1-d4b76331e3eb",
     "date": "2017-11-27T18:59:23"
   }
   }
   }
2. Message: Error during http call. HttpStatusCode: Unauthorized; 
   "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
   "message": "Access Token missing or malformed.",

The application has full control over all objects so it should not get an error with permissions issues

Comment: The 2nd error does not appear to be a problem with authorization/permissions, but with the token itself. Would you be able to share the contents of the token?

Comment: No problem, give me an idea on how to get the token contents, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Take your access token, and put it through a JWT decoder like this: http://shawntabrizi.com/jwt/

Comment: So you want the skip token? or access token?

Comment: "Take your **access token**...", '"message": "**Access Token** missing or malformed."',...

Comment: Having trouble pulling it up since the log file on the MA is 11 GB

Comment: ok I have checked the code and it pulls a new auth token when I run the MIM MA everytime. I am seeing if I can get the log that has it from this error.

Comment: I have pulled the two graph calls related to this error, but they are too long to post here.

Is there any other way to get the calls to you?

Comment: graph connector doesn’t log access token.
But this is interesting question, can this error happen when access token expired?
 - from the other resource working with me on the issue